# Functions with type signature Integer/Int: "type Integer does not match Int"

Tags: haskell

For

```
x :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]
x = take

y :: Integer -> [a] -> [a]
y _ [] = []
y n xs = take n xs
```

both Hugs and GHC report type errors:

```
ERROR "test.hs":5 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : take n xs
*** Term           : n
*** Type           : Integer
*** Does not match : Int

ERROR "test.hs":8 - Type error in explicitly typed binding
*** Term           : x
*** Type           : Int -> [a] -> [a]
*** Does not match : Integer -> [a] -> [a]
```

This is due to the fact that "take" has the signature "Int -> ...". Is there a way to tell the type system to either convert Integer to Int directly (without fromIntegral), or preferably (to keep the non-constrained size of Integer) to "construct" a version of take (or any other function explicitly using Int) for Integer? Or do I have to write my own versions of Prelude-Functions? Currently, my code is either littered with fromIntegral (and doesn't run if the Integer size exceeds the dimensions of Int) or with trivial re-implementations of standard functions, and that feels very clunky.

Answer (score 4):

Use [genericTake](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3agenericTake) from Data.List instead. The "generic" list functions receive Integer instead of the Int.

In the future, if you want to search for Haskell functions by type signature you can use [Hoogle](http://haskell.org/hoogle/)

---

In a more general sense, if all you want to do is add a conversion step you can use the built in composition operator to easily create your own functions.

```
--explicit type signature to force the less general types...
integerToInt :: Integer -> Int
integerToInt = fromIntegral

myGenericTake = take . integerToInt

--You can now use myGenericTake throughout the code.
```

Comment: take was merely an example. I'm still learning Haskell, and I tried to supplement the meager education I get at university by mucking about on my own, which is how I stumbled upon this. 

If I want to use any x :: Int -> ... with an Integer, that is then not possible? (Or only by using fromIntegral?)

Comment: @Max: added a small bit about function composition.

Comment: Thank you. Last question:

Can I in any way tell Haskell that I want it to use my implementation of a Prelude function (or any function) when it encounters a specific type? I would like to write a function 'take' (for example) with the signature take :: Integer -> ... and then have Haskell pick that when appropriate, so that I can use standard-names and not either "myTake" or "take . fromIntegral" in my code.

Comment: Haskell does not support that kind of C++-style overloading because it would mess up type inference. The only way to be able to give the same name to two different functions is using Type Classes. If you look at genericTake's type signature (`Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]) is precisely that overloaded version.

Comment: You can also import the Prelude hiding the original take so you can use the name for another function of your own instead. However, I wouldn't recommend doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Haskell takes the approach of *not* making *any* implicit casts. So when you are stuck with functions like `take`, you simply *need* to perform the explicit cast using `fromIntegral` or similar.

If that bugs you, then voice your opinion about improving Prelude. You would certainly not be alone in hoping for improved Prelude functions.